# Problème merge streams in background javascript of extension chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, merge, stream, video-streaming, blob

I want to record screen + camera + audio in my extension chrome

I use RecordRTC, when I send multiple streams (screen and camera) in constructor of RecordRTC an audio problem occurs after the second 30 of recording.

```
 new RecordRTC([stream,cameraStream], options);
```

But when I send one stream in RecordRTC no problem with audio

```
     new RecordRTC(cameraStream, options);
```

So I want to merge my streams (stream and cameraStream) and send the resulat stream in RecordRTC

I find the script [video-stream-merger](https://github.com/t-mullen/video-stream-merger) to merge streams

So my code of my background.js like this:

```
    var merger = new VideoStreamMerger();
    merger.addStream(stream , {
        index: 0
    });
    merger.addStream(cameraStream, {
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        x: 0,
        y:0,
        index: 1
    });
    merger.start();
    recorder = new RecordRTC(merger.result, options);
    recorder.startRecording();
```

But this script generate video with size 0 bytes

```
video/webm;codecs=vp8 -> 0 Bytes
```

When I put the same code in a content script of my extension it work fine et generate a resulat.

Why the script of merging streams not work in background.js of my extension ?

Comment: It may be a bug in Chrome. Or maybe these API can only work in a visible page.

Comment: There are others solutions to merge streams in background.js of extension?